# Call a function inside php file using webpack

Tags: php, jquery, webpack

i am using wepack for my PHP website.I could not call a jQuery function inside php blocks.I am getting the jquery error like 'ReferenceError: test1 is not defined'

This is my pages

> Index.php

```
<body>
    <script src="assets/js/packages/index.min.js"  type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <?php
    if($_SESSION['user']){
        ?>
        <script>
        test1();

        </script>
        <?php
    }else{
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

> index.js

```
var $   =   require("jquery");
function test1(){
    $('body').html("logined");//sample function

}
```

> webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
        'index': "./assets/js/index",
    },
  output: {
    path: __dirname+"/assets/js/packages",
    filename: "[name].min.js"
  },
   module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/,loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?sourceMap'},
            { test: /\.png$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=100000" },
            { test: /\.jpg$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=100000" },
            { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,loader : 'file-loader'},
            { test: /\.(png|woff)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }

        ]
    },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({$: "jquery",jQuery: "jquery","window.jQuery": "jquery"
}),
  ]
};
```

Comment: I guess you are indeed including `index.min.js` and not `index.js`? Same goes for `webpack.config.js`? :)

Comment: while exicuting wepack automaticaly create index.min.js file inside packages folder.

Comment: That's very nice, but I don't see the part you're "executing" webpack .. and add `type="text/javascript"` to your `<script>` tag executing `test1()` ..

Comment: Try to debug and see if index.min.js has actually loaded with test1

Answer (score 0):

I think that this as nothing to do with Webpack :
You should just wrap your `test1()` function in a dom ready function like this :

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    test1();
  });
</script>
```

This will avoid javascript from searching for a function that as is not yet loaded.